# Load data from IBM Object Storage file to Cloud DB2

Tags: db2, db2-luw, object-storage

I am using below SQL statement to load data from object storage file to cloud db2.

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('load from "S3::s3.jp-tok.objectstorage.softlayer.net::<s3-access-key-id>:
:<s3-secret-access-key>::nlu-test::practice_nlu.csv" of DEL modified by codepage=1208 
coldel0x7c WARNINGCOUNT 1000 MESSAGES ON SERVER INSERT into DASH12811.NLU_TEMP_2');
```

it failed with error :

```
Routine "SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD" execution has completed, but at least one error, "SQL3016", was encountered during the execution. More information is available.. SQLCODE=20397, SQLSTATE=01H52, DRIVER=4.24.92
```

Please note, i want to load this data to DB2 not DB2 warehouse.

Comment: Any reason you're not using the external table method, as recommended by IBM?

Comment: external table method works only in DB2 warehouse.

Answer (score 2):

When using `LOAD` via `ADMIN_CMD` the 1st result set from the stored procedure call contains a SQL statment that you can use to see the messages back from the `LOAD` command.

Here is an example of this from the CLP.

```
$ db2 "call admin_cmd('load from ''S3::s3.jp-tok.objectstorage.softlayer.net::<s3-access-key-id>::<s3-secret-access-key>::nlu-test::practice_nlu.csv'' of del modified by codepage=1208 coldel0x7c WARNINGCOUNT 1000 MESSAGES ON SERVER INSERT into t')"
 `  


  ROWS_READ            ROWS_SKIPPED         ROWS_LOADED          ROWS_REJECTED        ROWS_DELETED         ROWS_COMMITTED       ROWS_PARTITIONED     NUM_AGENTINFO_ENTRIES MSG_RETRIEVAL                                                                                     MSG_REMOVAL                                                          
  -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
                     -                    -                    -                    -                    -                    -                    -                     - SELECT SQLCODE, MSG FROM TABLE(SYSPROC.ADMIN_GET_MSGS('1618991872_2012791051_DB2INST1')) AS MSG   CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_REMOVE_MSGS('1618991872_2012791051_DB2INST1')     

  1 record(s) selected.

  Return Status = 0

SQL20397W  Routine "SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD" execution has completed, but at least 
one error, "SQL2018", was encountered during the execution. More information 
is available.  SQLSTATE=01H52
```

Now run the SQL from the result set `MSG_RETRIEVAL` column to see the detailed messages from `LOAD`

```
$ db2 "SELECT SQLCODE, MSG FROM TABLE(SYSPROC.ADMIN_GET_MSGS('1618991872_2012791051_DB2INST1')) AS MSG"

SQLCODE   MSG                                                                  
--------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL3501W  The table space(s) in which the table resides will not be placed in  
backup pending state since forward recovery is disabled for the database.      
SQL3109N  The utility is beginning to load data from file "S3".                
SQL3500W  The utility is beginning the "ANALYZE" phase at time "10/01/2019     
18:27:29.090523".                                                              
SQL2018N  The utility encountered an error "" while attempting to verify the   
user's authorization ID or database authorizations.                            
SQL2018N  The utility encountered an error "" while attempting to verify the   
user's authorization ID or database authorizations.                            

  5 record(s) selected.
```

Looking at the full LOAD messages may help you see what issue you have with your call

Comment: it is showing empty result set when executing SELECT SQLCODE, MSG FROM TABLE(SYSPROC.ADMIN_GET_MSGS('XXXXXXXXXXX_BLUADMIN')) AS MSG command.

Comment: Is that using the message literal returned from the original call?  If so, you might need to raise a Case with IBM support

Comment: @PaulVernon SQL3016N is about an invalid LOAD command option, which would mean the command did not run and therefore no messages were generated.

Comment: Yes, I did spot that, but then the command posted ran for me (all be it on a different db2 level I suspect), so I did not just want to repeat that error message back to the OP.  But maybe I will  do that now

Comment: i copied this command from ibm docs and executing this from ibm web console. when i pasted it on notepad, command was in 3 lines. once i tried to execute command in single line by removing new line characters. it worked fine. sorry. i should have thought of this before.

Answer (score 1):

Error SQL3016 is

```
$ db2 "? SQL3016"


SQL3016N  An unexpected keyword "<keyword>" was found in the filetmod
      parameter for the filetype.

Explanation:

A keyword that does not apply to the filetype for the utility was found
in the filetype modifier (the filetmod parameter or the phrase following
MODIFIED BY in a CLP command).

The utility stops processing.

User response:

Remove the filetype modifier or specify at least one valid keyword in
the filetype modifier. See the Command Reference for more information on
filetype modifiers.
```

Which indicates that one of your filetype modifiers is not valid. Although they do appear valid, ti would be interesting to test if the the load without the `codepage=1208` or `coldel0x7c` modifiers works or gives a different error for you

Comment: i tried with one sample csv with one column and small data, it worked fine when i execute this query in single line after removing new line characters. since my input file is csv with tab delimited, i used 0x09 as delimiter.